# Debugging a redirect loop affecting only certain pages

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am trying to fix a site which has several redirects that seem to have been added via a plugin called [Peters plugin redirect](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/peters-login-redirect). The plugin has since been deactivated and delated but the redirects loop is stil present. I have tried the following:

- deactivating and deleting the plugin
- refreshing the permalinks
- clearing and resetting the htaccess defining the home and site url in wp-config
- deleting the rewrite rules in the options table

No caching plugin is being used and the problem remains in Private browsing mode. 
The only two pages affected are the home page and the registration page.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this or any suggestions on how to go about debugging.

EDIT: I found [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21602) which might have something to do with the issue as the site owner likes to use capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be cacheing problem. WP Super Cache had been installed and deleted(uninstalled -perhaps incorrectly) but the advanced-cache.php file remained in wp-content.

Answer (score 0):

You've deactivated it, but did you **uninstall** it?

Looks like a table was created and there's an uninstall function in there that removes the database table with some redirects in there.

I would give that a shot.

But before you do anything, back up your database and files.

Comment: Thanks @richard I did actually uninstall it and refreshed the permalinks afterwards for good measure.